# Running a script when a Mac package is executed

Tags: macos

I have a Mac OS X application in the standard .app format and was wondering what is the easiest way to have a small script execute before the main program does. Is that possible?

**Edit:**

I only want to run the script once, so if I can set a flag or something after it runs that would be great!

**Second Edit:**

I do not have the XCode project so I cannot recompile anything, which is why I'm looking for another method.

Comment: Are you building this app in xcode from source, or are you wrapping a packaged .app that you've been handed and/or can't recompile?

Comment: It's an Adobe AIR application, so I'm trying to install Adobe AIR if it hasn't been installed already. It's not a standard app (some files have been modified to support hardware integration) so I cannot use the standard AIR distribution mechanism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the app is relatively simple, you could just repackage it in another bundle.  You could write a short program to run the script and then launch their executable, which you'd want to include in your bundle as a resource.

Of course, you'd also need to copy over all the original resources from the application.

Might I ask which program you are trying to run in this way?

Comment: It's an Adobe AIR application, so I'm trying to install Adobe AIR if it hasn't been installed already. It's not a standard app (some files have been modified to support hardware integration) so I cannot use the standard AIR distribution mechanism.

Answer (score 3):

Two possibilities:

- If you have access to the Xcode project, you can put your script in the resources of your app, get its pathname with:

  ```
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"preamble" ofType:@"sh"]
  ```

  and invoque it with a simple `system()` call at the beginning of your `main()` function.
- If you don't have access to the Xcode project, I am not certain whether it is possible. I would try something like substituting actual executable with your script and add a way to call the executable at the end of the script with an `exec` command.